# Using Google Places API for restaurant discovery

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

So i was reading through the terms of service for the Google Places API, and I'm confused about a couple of points in the terms and conditions.

> No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services. You will not use Google’s Content or Services to create or augment your own mapping-related dataset (or that of a third party), including a mapping or navigation dataset, business listings database, mailing list, or telemarketing list.
>
> No use of Content in a listings service. You will not use business listings-related Content in any Customer Implementation that has the primary purpose of making available business, residential address, or telephone directory listings.

Do these two things interfere with creating a restaurant discovery app? All I'm trying to do is locate different restaurants in the area, and figure out whether a user will like them or not.

Comment: IANAL but if you just fetch the data, display a list and then display on a Google Maps view then you should be fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues) not coding.